# check if a string ends with a name in CMake

Tags: regex, cmake

I want to check if the `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` variable ends with a specific name. I need to use `MATCHES` for it, but it does not seems to work.

I've written:

```
if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR MATCHES "*MyFolderName")
# code
endif()
```

But it does not work. I obtain the following error:

```
RegularExpression::compile(): ?+* follows nothing.
RegularExpression::compile(): Error in compile
```

What can I do in order to fix the match?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Usually, in regular expressions "*" means "repeat preceding zero or more times". CMake is not exception. For match at the end of string, use `$`:

```
CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR MATCHES "MyFolderName$"
```

CMake regular expressions are described [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/string.html#regex-specification).

Comment: Thanks, also for the useful link.

Answer (score 7):

`MATCH` require a regular expression, not a "file glob" (wildcard).

```
if(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR MATCHES ".*MyFolderName")
   # ...
endif()
```

or even try this: `.*/MyFolderName`. But it also would match `/some/MyFolderName/path`... Use `.*/MyFolderName$` to match the last path name component.

Comment: This doesn't work if `CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR` contains `+` or any character that are used in regular expressions, see: https://developer.blender.org/T65852